# CallKit: obtain a list of currently blocked phone numbers

Tags: ios, callkit

Is it possible to use CallKit to obtain a list of all phone numbers that have been blocked across all CallKit extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. A CallKit extension can only add numbers to the list.  There is no API for retrieving blocked numbers